# CallKit :- Callkit is working but the callee doesn't get the call

Tags: swift, xcode, callkit, openurl

I want to develop an SOS application. When I am trying to use URL schema openURL(), it will display an alert but my requirement is to connect the call without any alert or popup while trying to call. So I found a solution using CallKit. When I implemented CallKit in my application it does not ask for any permission, the outgoing call is placed but the callee doesn't get any call. Is there any solution for this?

I have tried the following code for connecting the call.

```
@IBAction func buttonCallTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let provider = CXProvider(configuration: CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "My App"))
    provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    let controller = CXCallController()
    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: CXStartCallAction(call: UUID(), handle: CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: "\(number)")))
    controller.request(transaction, completion: { error in })

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 5) {
        provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: controller.callObserver.calls[0].uuid, connectedAt: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any iOS application can't make native call without user action.

**An alert will be shown with phone number and two buttons will be available "Call" and "Cancel" which is presented from the OS level.**

Just like we are showing popup to delete photos from Photos app.

### Solution

> If you want to implement SOS Application (Yes its possible using VoIP
>   service), But you can place calls when app is active (Can be done
>   without user action given internet connection is there.)

**Note: The receiving side also should support VoIP.**

### How to Implement VoIP

We need **permission** of Voice over IP services to make calls in between iPhone devices.

> VoIP app must have background mode enabled in the Xcode Project >
>   Capabilities pane. Select the checkbox for Voice over IP

Also CallKit is indented only for VoIP Apps, If you really want to implement the VoIP follow [CallKit Tutorial](https://websitebeaver.com/callkit-swift-tutorial-super-easy)

Answer (score 2):

You just can't make standard native calls through CallKit. The CallKit framework, as clearly stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit), is meant to be used to develop custom VoIP applications and integrate them with the native phone interface.